# Isometries of hyperbolic plane

Tags: differential-geometry

How can i show that the metric of minkowski (or hyperboloid model) is the same that half plane model without use calculus of complex variables?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871602/minkowski-plane-vs-hyperbolic-plane).

Comment: I saw this post but i did not understand it. how can i connect the two metrics? the writer of this post say " you can check that the metrics are the same" but it isn't very clear.

Comment: Do you know how to pull back differential forms/tensors?

Comment: a little bit yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand on the discussion in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3487139/how-to-convert-between-the-hyperboloid-model-and-the-poincare-ball-when-the-curv).

Consider the Lorentz metric $ds^2_L=dx^2+dy^2-dz^2$ on $3$-space and take the (half) hyperboloid $z=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$. To map to the Poincaré disk, we send $(x,y,z)$ to $(\frac xz,\frac yz,1)$, then to $(\frac xz,\frac yz,0)$, then to the unit sphere at $(\frac xz,\frac yz,\frac 1z)$. Finally, we stereographically project from the south pole to the unit disk and map to $\frac1{z+1}(x,y)$. You can check that the inverse mapping — from the Poincaré disk to the hyperboloid — is
$$f(u,v) = \frac1{1-(u^2+v^2)}(2u,2v,1+u^2+v^2).$$
(You should check that this point actually does lie on the hyperboloid.)

We have
\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{2u}{1-(u^2+v^2)},\\
y&=\frac{2v}{1-(u^2+v^2)},\\
z&=\frac{1+u^2+v^2}{1-(u^2+v^2)},
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
f^*dx&=\frac{2(1+u^2-v^2)du + 4uv\,dv}{(1-(u^2+v^2))^2},\\
f^*dy&=\frac{4uv\,du + 2(1-u^2+v^2)dv}{(1-(u^2+v^2))^2},\\
f^*dz&=\frac{4(u\,du+v\,dv)}{(1-(u^2+v^2))^2}.
\end{align*}
Now let's compute the pullback $f^*ds^2_L$ of the Lorentz metric on the hyperboloid.
We have
\begin{align*}
f^*(dx^2+dy^2-dz^2) &= (f^*dx)^2 + (f^*dy)^2 - (f^*dz)^2 \\
&= \frac {4(du^2+dv^2)}{(1-(u^2+v^2))^2},
\end{align*}
which is the metric on the Poincaré disk with constant curvature $-1$.

You can convert this to the upper half-plane by pulling back by any standard conformal mapping from the half-plane to the disk.

Comment: So, to connect the metric of the minkowski model to upper half metric i can use the poincaré  disk as a bridge because its metric is isometric to the upper-half plane? This argument is interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Right. This metric on the disk is isometric to the usual metric $\dfrac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ on the half-plane.